# Open Location setting intent after permission granted.

Tags: android, android-studio

in my app i am requesting location permission from the user once the permission granted i want to check whether location is on or not,if it is not active then i want user to navigate to the settings activity where they can enable location. 
Here is the code i am trying to achieve the above condition,but after granting permission when location is not enable it is not navigating to the settings activity.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } 

  //This will run when permission is already granted.

else {

            if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){


                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

            }

            else {
                mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                if (mLocation != null) {

                    String str1 = hereLocation(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude());
                    fragText.setText(str1);

                    sendLocation(str1);

                }

            }

        }

    }

 else{

 //For Api level below 23

   if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) 
{

           startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

        }

   else {
                mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                if (mLocation != null) {

               String str1 = hereLocation(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude());
               fragText.setText(str1);

                    sendLocation(str1);

                }

            }

   }

    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){


        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

           if( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){

                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

            }

            else {
                mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

                if (mLocation != null) {

                   String str1 = hereLocation(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude());
                   fragText.setText(str1);

                   sendLocation(str1);

                }

            }
        }
        else{

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            TastyToast.makeText(getActivity(),"Unable to get location",TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know the problem in above code.

**THANKS**

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not navigating to the settings activity*? Is there any error?

Comment: No error is not showing,but after permission granted it remains on the same activity even if location is not enable.I want to launch settings activity so that user can enable location and get back to app.

Comment: The intent you are using should work. Enable debug and make sure your code block is hit.